# Publish to iTunes invalid profile

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, provisioning-profile, application-loader

i'm trying to publish application on iTunes but...

1) if I publish it via xcode 8 (automatically signing), it passed validation and uppload application, but it noappears in iTunes.

2) next i (grow up version code) truing to use ApplicationLoader and got error:
[image]

3) then i remove all developer and distribution keys from keychain and downloads it again
[image]

4) and trying to set up it manually but got an error:
[image]

p.s 
all certificates are valid

i'ts not my user, so i dosen't have access to remove and create new certificates

certificates have been set in build settings also:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might because you did not add permission in Info.plist like

Privacy - Camera Usage Description and Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

You can found all the permissions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

Comment: thank you. i've come back automatically signing, added permission and now it's ok

Comment: The question mentioned nothing about photo library usage.  How does this answer address the problem, which was obviously a code signing issue?

Comment: @wottle photo library is just an example, because mostly app using this permission.

Comment: @wottle yes, i've added permissions that my application requested. but the issue is that application loader shows error that profile is invalid, but the reason - permissions absence